# ASP.NET priority of styling with AJAX Toolkit DropShadow Extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a website that I would like to add more styling to.  On many of the pages, I have an ASP.NET Panel control.  I added the DropShadow Extender to the control and it provides rounded corners but the shadow effect is not displaying.  There are many other CSS styles being used on the page.  The only CSS style used for the panel is the background color.  How can I get the shadow to appear?  I think that other styles on the page are blocking the shadow from appearing.  I want the shadow to trump all other styles on the page for that control.  Is that possible?

Comment: pls mention your target browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the style that was blocking the shadow from appearing was the CSS Styling:

border-collapse:      collapse;

To fix it, I add the following to the CSS Styling for the Panel:

border-collapse:    separate;

Now the shadow displays as it should.